# Where to ask a question if it would fit into different SE sites?

Tags: discussion, site-crossover

I'm currently interested in (programming) home automation with the rasp-pi.

The question is now where is the best place for that?

[StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), because it is about programing?

[Rasp-Pi beta](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com), because it runs there?

or on the upcoming [Home-Automation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55835/home-automation) (when we get the missing 28 users)?

Or, is it a better idea to copy (duplicate) the article?

Comment: I'm mostly interested in a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **ask a question** about programming on Raspberry PI, the [Rasp-Pi beta](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) is the wrong place. Their [help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> Off-topic:
>
> Questions about programming that are not related to its usage on the Raspberry Pi. These will probably be better off on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

So there you have your answer. If your question is about implementation issues, [Stackoverflow](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is probably the best fit. If it is about software architecture and design, [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is.

Comment: Unfortunately, the questions will be related to the usage on the raspi, because it uses hardware that is only avilable for the raspi.

Comment: If it is about programming that hardware, as in your question, it is still development. On SO there are questions about VHDL too.